# jQuery UI Tooltip bug

Tags: jquery, tooltip, visibility, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using the jQuery UI tool for tooltips and I've found a peculiar bug that I can't duplicate (to show you) or get rid of. Usually, this tool will use the `title="whatever"` part of a tag to give you a fancy css version of a hover tag. This is working, but it is also picking up the title of my page `<head><title>My Page</title></head>` and display it in the bottom left corner. Also, it's never the same tooltip number either, otherwise I could just ignore that instance. Example `#ui-tooltip-0`. I need to prevent tooltip from collecting my title tag. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me code so i can check?

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to initialize the UI Tooltip? Maybe you're using the wrong settings and/or selector

Comment: $(document).tooltip(); It's the most basic call.

Comment: @triplethreat77, unique `ui-tooltip-*` ids are by design, but the widget definitely should not match your `<title>` element. Could it be that your `<head>` element also exposes a `title` *attribute*?

Comment: nothing in the title tag, just placed as above. How can I write an exception for that one tag?

Comment: use something like :not(title) in the selector

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me:

```
$('body').tooltip()
```

Cheers